# To to build reusable, configurable .NET Core extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

For few days I am trying to find any good information about this problem.

I would like to build the module which I will be able to re-use later on in other applications. What is important it has to be configurable.

- I need to be able to extend DbContext (add models from my module)
- I need information how to configure my module from the main application.

I was trying to find any tutorial/docs about both of the problems but couldn't find anything. I know how to create the method to be able to call `services.AddMyModule()` but I cannot find anything about passing the configuration and using it inside the module later on.

I would really appreciate any help. I hope it is clear what I am asking about.

Comment: I cannot understand close flag as off-topic - really? Also it is not too broad. I have clearly asked 2 questions in the list what I am asking about..

Comment: 2 pieces of advice: 1) Read the book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://www.manning.com/books/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition) 2) Read about [database migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations) and don't assume the host application will only have 1 `DbContext`

Comment: 2. That's right but even with creating own DbContext which is good idea, I need to somehow configure the connection like e.g. npgsql

Comment: When using DI properly, all application configuration (such as database connections) happens at application startup. Your module will therefore generally need to provide the tools to the consumer of the module to be able to provide this information. See [DI friendly library](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/). What this generally means for a .NET Core application extension is to provide an extension method or 2 in which the configuration info will be provided and passed along to the components that use the config (via constructor) that are registered with the DI container.

Comment: What prevents you from exposing the function callback with same signature to as `AddDbContext` to your `AddMyModule` method??! Such as `services.AddMyModule(dbConfig => dbConfig.UseSqlServer(...))`?

Comment: @tseng any help how? That's what I'm asking for, I don't know where to start

Comment: You never used delegates and `Func<T1, T2>`?

Comment: I am still learning... Could you help with some good link about this topis?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your static `IServiceCollection` method with additional parameters, such as

```
public static MyModuleServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyModule(this IServiceCollection services, Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>> config
    {
        ...
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(config);
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you can call it in your app like

```
services.AddMyModule(dbConfig => {
    dbConfig.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});
```